# Bootstrap Modal Form Saving Everything BUT Select Options

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a modal window that is saving all data but the select form :

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tax_code_modal">Tax Code</label>
                    <select value="" name="tax_code_modal" id="tax_code_modal" placeholder="Tax Code" class="form-control">
                            <option value="None" <?= ($data['taxcode']) == 'None' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>None</option>
                            <option value="Tax" <?= ($data['taxcode']) == 'Tax' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Tax</option>
                            <option value="Fxt" <?= ($data['taxcode']) == 'Fxt' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Fxt</option>
                        </select>
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
```

I suspect I have something wrong with the above code, but cant seem to see whats right in front of me....

Here is more relevant code :

```
$.ajax({
         url: "ajax.php",
         dataType: "json",
         method: 'post',
         data: {
            data : data,
            type: 'saveNewProduct'
         },
         success: function(result){
            if( (typeof result.success !== "undefined") && result.success ){
$('#taxcode_'+element_id).val($('#tax_code_modal').val());      
message('success', PRODUCT_ADD_SUCCESS);
            }else{
                message('fail', PRODUCT_ADD_FAIL);
            }
        }
     });


}
```

Database code :

```
$taxcode = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db->con, trim( $data['taxcode'] ) );
```

The code not included is just stupid simple querys, etc not relevant

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this line :

```
<select value="" name="tax_code_modal" id="tax_code_modal" placeholder="Tax Code" class="form-control">
```

to this :

```
<select value="<?= ($data['taxcode']) == 'None' ? 'selected' : '' ?>" name="tax_code_modal" id="tax_code_modal" placeholder="Tax Code" class="form-control">
```